# AWS - IAM Identity Center configuration delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I think I need to be re assured.
I created an AWS Identity Center in AWS but in the wrong region. I have made no configuration yet.
If I delete the IAM Identity Center configuration to re-create one in the good region, will it delete IAM user, groups, roles and policies in "normal" IAM ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Both are separate AWS services. If you delete "***IAM Identity Center***" and enable it again in another region, it will not affect any IAM users in "***IAM***" service. The users and groups in "***IAM Identity Center***" will be affected.